# Serial.println works only inside of loop()

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

My code

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial) {}
  Serial.println("Setup");
}

int t = 0;

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Loop1");
  if (t==0){
    t = 1;
    Serial.println("Loop2");
  }
}
```

All that is printed is Loop1 (indefinetly).

Edit: added !serial as suggested by @aMike

Any idea?

Comment: In order to get the Loop2 part to work, try putting the `int t=0;` inside the `setup()` section

Comment: Read the Serial docs to find out why you need to wait for the serial device to become ready inside `setup`: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/ifserial/   That might also explain why the Loop1 got lost (if it really did).

Comment: @Spyre It's out of scope if it's defined inside of setup()

Comment: @aMike I've added the !Serial, but there is no difference in terminal monitor

Comment: Read a datasheet and you'll understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a short delay after establishing the serial connection:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  delay(500); // this will ensure displaying your content on the serial monitor
Serial.println("Setup");
}
```

Comment: delay(500) was, as you said, the thing that made it work. I don't even need to add while (!Serial).

Comment: Sure, it works, nevertheless please understand that using `while (!Serial)` is very useful when you want to make sure the program is waiting for the communication to be established before doing other things (in other words when you want to ensure a host computer is connected).